# Не получается завести проект React + Typescript + Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, typescript, leafletjs

Создал проект в VS как `Standalone TypeScript React Project` + `leaflet`.

Пытаюсь завести проект в простейшей конфигурации, поднять простейшую карту и потом уже усложнять.

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { MyMap } from './myMap';
import './App.css';
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
    displayName: string = App.name;
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                  <header className="App-header">
                    <div> <MyMap /> </div> 
              </header>
    </div>
        );
    }
}
```

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

myMap

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

export const MyMap: FC = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false} id="map">
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
                    <Popup>
                        A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                    </Popup>
                </Marker>
            </MapContainer>

        </div>
    );
};
```

Два вида ошибок:

1. В `index.html` в `<head>` добавлены два линка `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" ...>`
   и  `<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" ....>`. Версии `leaflet@1.9.4` соответствуют моему пакету.
   Ругается на вторую ссылку:

   > - Error parsing 'integrity' attribute (...) The digest must be a valid, base64-encoded value.
   > - Error parsing 'integrity' attribute ('...'). The hash algorithm must be one of 'sha256', 'sha384',    or 'sha512', followed by a '-'
   >   character.

На эту тему мало что нашёл, и ни одного случая с `leaflet`. Пробовал менять версии лифлета - и всего пакета, и соответственно указанной здесь ссылки, не помогло. Удалял всё из `npm_modules`, тоже ничего. Можно ли вообще обойтись без этой ссылки?

2. Ругается на 'хуки, которые определены вне функции'. Но у меня в коде ни одного хука! И соответственно, нечего исправлять.

> Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the
> body of a function component.  This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem. printWarning @ react.development.js:209
>    react.development.js:1622 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties
>    of null (reading 'useState')
>    at useState (react.development.js:1622:1)
>    at MapContainerComponent (MapContainer.js:19:1)
>    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
>    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226:1)
>    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636:1)
>    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
>    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
>    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
>    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
>    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)

Версии пакетов ('npm list')

> +-- @types/leaflet@1.9.3
> +-- @types/react-leaflet@3.0.0
> +-- bootstrap@5.3.1
> +-- leaflet@1.9.4
> +-- react-bootstrap@2.8.0
> +-- react-dom@18.2.0
> +-- react@18.2.0 `-- reactstrap@9.2.0

Comment: Зачем вам троеточие в линках? И зачем это вообще делать, если вы импортируете библиотеку в проекте? У вас App это класс, возможно идет конфликт с фукнциональными компонентами. Попробуйте заменить App на фукнцию

Comment: переделал App  в функцию:

`export default function App() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                  <header className="App-header">
                      <h5>map is bellow</h5>
                    <div> <MyMap1 /> </div> 
              </header>
    </div>
        );
}
`

ошибка та же:
`
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component....`

Comment: вот похожий случай, остался без решения  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76730776/asp-net-core-with-react-js-react-leaflet-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of

Comment: Удалил проект, создал заново 'Standalone TypeScript React Project' - заводится. Доставил 'npm install --save leaflet' & 'npm install --save @types/leaflet @types/geojson' - та же самая ошибка "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. 
...Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При обычной установке ([как здесь](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/start-installation/?ref=xloypaypa.pub)) все 3 пакета с лифлетом не прописывались в package.json/dependencies, и соответственно нормально не экспортировались.
Почему так получилось - осталось непонятым.

Как сделал:

1. Удалить всё из папки node_modules.
2. `npm install` - заново поставили пакеты
3. `npm install leaflet prop-types react react-dom react-leaflet -D @types/leaflet` - поставили пакеты с лифлетом. Главное здесь `prop-types`.

Возможно, помогли бы манипуляции с  `--save-dev` (целиком или частями) либо с ключами.